# SQL Server 2008 - Implementing DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, decode

First, I know there are plenty of posts etc relating to the use of CASE in place of DECODE, but they don't appear to fit with my concern.

I am trying to convert an Oracle PL/SQL procedure to SQL Server.  The procedure builds a SQL statement dynamically, and uses the DECODE function to create a x-tab. The procedure is as so:

```
PROCEDURE GET_XFORM_DATALOGS (
    fLOTCODE IN VARCHAR2,
    THEDATA OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

    -- VARIABLE DECLARATIONS

    TYPE loc_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40);  -- array type
    loc_array    loc_array_type;     -- array for test names

    prod VARCHAR2(20);  --  product ID
    step VARCHAR2(20);  --  step ID
    sql_str VARCHAR2(32000);    -- SQL statement


    -- EXECUTABLE CODE

    BEGIN -- executable part starts here

        -- get the test names for the given lot code
        SELECT 
            PT_TESTNAME BULK COLLECT INTO loc_array
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    TESTPARMS.PT_TESTNAME, 
                    TESTPARMS.PT_TESTNUM
                FROM 
                    "PRETEST".PRETEST_LOT@PRS_DBLINK LOT,
                    "PRETEST".PRETEST_MEASURE@PRS_DBLINK MEASURE,
                    "PRETEST".PRETEST_TEST_PARMS@PRS_DBLINK TESTPARMS
                WHERE 
                    LOT.PT_LOTSQ = MEASURE.PT_LOTSQ AND
                    MEASURE.PT_LOTSQ = TESTPARMS.PT_LOTSQ AND
                    MEASURE.PT_TESTNUM = TESTPARMS.PT_TESTNUM AND
                    LOT.PT_LOTID = fLOTCODE
                ORDER BY
                PT_TESTNUM
            );

        -- build the SQL string
        sql_str := '';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   'SELECT ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOTID, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOCTYPE, ' ;
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_LOT.PT_TESTDATE, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_WAFERID, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_XCOORD, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_YCOORD, ';

        -- add the decodes for column headings
        FOR i IN loc_array.first..loc_array.last LOOP
            sql_str := sql_str || 'max ( decode ( PRETEST_TEST_PARMS.PT_TESTNAME, '''
                || loc_array(i) || ''', PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_MEAS_VALUE, null ) ) '
                || loc_array(i);
                IF (i < loc_array.last) THEN
                    sql_str := sql_str || ', ';
                END IF;
        END LOOP;

        -- build the remainder of the SQL
        sql_str := sql_str || ' FROM ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     "PRETEST".PRETEST_LOT@PRS_DBLINK PRETEST_LOT, ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     "PRETEST".PRETEST_MEASURE@PRS_DBLINK PRETEST_MEASURE, ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     "PRETEST".PRETEST_TEST_PARMS@PRS_DBLINK PRETEST_TEST_PARMS ';

        sql_str := sql_str || ' WHERE  ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOTSQ = PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_LOTSQ AND ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_LOTSQ = PRETEST_TEST_PARMS.PT_LOTSQ AND ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_TESTNUM = PRETEST_TEST_PARMS.PT_TESTNUM AND ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     (PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOTID = :fFLOTCODE)  ';

        sql_str := sql_str || ' GROUP BY ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOTID,  ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_LOT.PT_LOCTYPE,  ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_LOT.PT_TESTDATE,  ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_WAFERID, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_XCOORD, ';
        sql_str := sql_str ||   '   PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_YCOORD ';

        sql_str := sql_str || ' ORDER BY  ';
        sql_str := sql_str || '     PRETEST_LOT.PT_TESTDATE  ';

        -- run the query
        OPEN THEDATA FOR sql_str USING fLOTCODE;

END GET_XFORM_DATALOGS;
```

The question I have is, is this going to be possible to implement in SQL Server?  I can't seem to work out how to use CASE WHEN THEN etc to create column headings based on the dynamic data.

Sorry if what I've asked is unclear.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

BBz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the Oracle equivalent using CASE would be:

```
sql_str := sql_str || 'max ( CASE WHEN PRETEST_TEST_PARMS.PT_TESTNAME = '''
    || loc_array(i) || ''' THEN PRETEST_MEASURE.PT_MEAS_VALUE END ) '
    || loc_array(i);
```

So try converting that to SQL Server instead.

Comment: Ahh, ok thanks for pointing that out. Will have a look, although I think the 8000 max chars in sql_str won't be enough :s

Comment: @bob you can use varchar (max) from the SQL_ Str variable